# How can I reduce ram usage? And also how can I speed up Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: performance, ram

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 14.10 from 14.04 to find the amount of ram usage has almost doubled well my CPU usage and almost been reduced. 
When doing little on my computer my ram usage stays at about 1.4gb well my CPU stays between 4% and 16%. 
How can I reduce my ram usage?

Also, even though Ubuntu runs great with little or no lag at all, when opening programs such as firefox or the ubuntu software centre the loading time increases to almsot 5 seconds. On 14.04 the loading time was about 2 to 3 seconds. 
How can I reduce loading times and increase performance?

Comment: we need more information. use top or `free -m` for more info on ram use. I do not think using less ram is going to change performance as unused ram is wasted ram. much more likely a bad driver, either a bad wireless or video driver.

Answer (score 1):

First you should open the terminal input the command free, then past the results it here.
So that we may help you.

If you prefer here are some patches not solutions:

I would recommend a full clean install. (at the bottom I have explained how to do it)

A quick patch not a solution might be installing gnome partition editor.

Then resize your partition.
The format the knew allocated space (e.g. 2gb=2048 MB) as swap area.
Here is a good video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xLur2TfNVXE

Here is a tutorial how to do a clean install: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop
There a good video in portuguese with a creation of swap area in youtube. It is called Instalação do Linux Ubuntu 13.10 (Dual Boot com Windows 7).

Where you should mount the ubuntu image into a usb portable hdd or cd.

Then boot from there. Normally you have boot while long pressing F12 or F2 or ESC key to choose the place where you want to boot from.

Next you will see a screen where you can cancel or continue. Click continue.

Then choose installation type as "something else".

Create 2 partiton 1 with 2gb (2048 MB) and the other with the rest of space you have left.
The 2 gb one is optional. If you create it you should change it's type to swap area.
And the first one to journalling  ext4. and choose the mounting point as "/". Choose this partition to install your ubuntu.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: RAM is meant to be used, as having apps and processes ready to go when you want them saves you time. Something else is going on here,  as a swap file or partition is normally used only when you have higher memory use than you report.  Let's get a little more detail: Please click on the grey edit link above on the left, and post the results of running _free - m_

Comment: sorry i am bit of newbie, i do not much yet... just trying to help... please help him...

Comment: AS k7AAY said you should goo into the terminal and type free and then post here the results. Here is an example: http://askubuntu.com/questions/522853/ubuntu-14-too-high-memory-usage