# Swap being used and performance sluggish even though I have 8 gig of RAM?

Tags: swap

I have read [Why is swap being used even though I have plenty of free RAM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157793/why-is-swap-being-used-even-though-i-have-plenty-of-free-ram) the thread, which was very helpful, however I have 8 gigs of ram installed, (mentioned in the thread as masses of ram), and am still having swap problems.

The ram usage seldom exceeds 4 gigs, but after a few hours the computer becomes significantly sluggish, and any time I check with system monitor, a small amount of swap is in use. The problem seems to be related to Firefox.

Comment: It's really hard to answer this. Check system monitor when it becomes slow to see which programs are using ram. If it's firefox, check your extensions etc. etc.

Comment: A small amount of swap should always be in use. On every Ubuntu machine I have, there's always some usage. That isn't the issue. It's possible there's something wrong with your hard drive. Use this to check your drive health: http://askubuntu.com/questions/38566/how-can-i-check-the-health-of-my-hard-drive