# Swpd and Free Memory

Tags: server, ram, swap

I'm tryng to stress a web server with requests, I used `vmstat` to get the memory usage of the server, but I don't understand few things.

1. When the requests start, the free memory decreases and the swpd increases, but after a while, even if the requests continue at the same rate, the free memory goes up. I think it's because the system goes out of free memory, or at least to avoid that before it's to late, allocates new memory with swap memory, am I right?
2. Is there a way to limit the swap memory allocation?

[image: Memory Usage Compared]

Comment: 1) Could you add the graph for mem used by application too ? 2) Why  do you want to reduce swap allocation ? Do you have bad performance ?

Comment: 1) Unfortunately no

2) I want to test the performances without the swap memory

Comment: As long as you have free memory swap doesn't impact performance in any way. But if you wan't, you can disable swap bu running `sudo swapoff -a`

Comment: Perfect thanks. Also is there a way to set a specific dimension, same for buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No: Free memory is unused memory: you're not going out of memory at all.
2. It's possible, but a bad idea: the kernel knows better than you when to use swap...  **;-)**

For more information on how the kernel uses memory, [have a look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/159358/344926).