# Swapiness update is not working

Tags: kernel, ram, swap

I've looked a lot of blog posts and threads and can't find someone who has the same problem as I do.

This is my system:

- Ubuntu 18.04 kernel 4.15 (headless)
- AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor
- 16Gb ram
- 2Gb swap
- 120Gb ssd

I read [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157793/why-is-swap-being-used-even-though-i-have-plenty-of-free-ram) (I also checked on [linux documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt)) on how to reduce swapiness and I set it to 10 (validated by `cat /proc/sys/vm/swappines` and was originally at 60).

But my system still fulls my ram to 39% then start swapping. Using htop it always shows 39% of ram usage and 99% of swap usage. Each reboot always reaches 39% until it starts swapping.

I'm sorry if this has been asked, but all I can find is "reduce swapiness" which I already did and doesn't look it's really working. Is there another file to edit than `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please check the current level of swapiness:  `sudo sysctl -a | grep swap` will show the current operating value

Comment: It says `vm.swappiness = 10`. I thought that this is supposed to represent a ratio (like 10 -> 10% swap, 90% ram).